# How to read a big text file into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a big txt file and I need to use some complex pandas functions, that I cannot acomplish with Dask Dataframe.

Some I'm reading this text with chucksize, but later I need to convert it into a DataFrame, without consuming so much memory.

```py
big_list = []
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv("some_big_file.txt", chunksize=chunksize):
     big_list.append(chunk)

df = pd.DataFrame(big_list)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The only advantage you are taking of by reading in chunk is lower RAM consumption or the footprint which will be higher when you're reading the entire file at once, but your dataframe is still going to have it's required `RAM` consumed, if the data file is really huge, I'd suggest you to convert each `chunk` to `categorical` and then append it a dataframe, this way, your dataframe will remain in compact form and require less memory.

```py
allChunk = pd.DataFrame()
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv("some_big_file.txt", chunksize=chunksize):
     chunk = chunk.astype('category')
     if allChunk.empty: # Assign first chunk directly to allChunk
          allChunk = chunk
          continue
     for eachCol in chunk:  # use union_categoircals for each column
          colUnion = pd.api.types.union_categoricals([allChunk[eachCol], chunk[eachCol]])
          allChunk[eachCol] = pd.Categorical(allChunk[eachCol], categories=colUnion.categories)
          chunk[eachCol] = pd.Categorical(chunk[eachCol], categories=colUnion.categories)

    allChunk = pd.concat([allChunk, chunk])  # concatenate the chunk to final dataframe

# Your final dataframe is in `allChunk`
```

**PS**: *Instead of converting all columns to categorical, you may want to do it more selectively, you can search for different strategies for doing so*.